# digital ocean error ! 502 bad gateway (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, digital-ocean, puma

So I've reset my digital ocean droplets root password, and now I'm getting a 502 bad gateway error when visiting the site.

Here is a snapshot of the nginx_logs:

```
2016/04/26 14:34:09 [error] 4019#0: *4 connect() to 
unix:/home/apane/redoakproject/tmp/sockets/puma.sock failed 
(111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, 
client: *.*.*.*.*, server: directrenos.com, request: 
"GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/apane/redoakproject/tmp/sockets/puma.sock:/", 
host: "directrenos.com"
```

How can I get it up and running again?

Thanks!

Comment: Your puma app server isn't set up properly -- unix:/home/apane/redoakproject/tmp/sockets/puma.sock failed - look at the permissions on your puma.sock file and make sure it's writeable by your app.

Comment: But it was running before, what could have happened? Is there a way to reboot it?

Comment: @9umber :~/redoakproject/tmp/sockets$ cat puma.sock 
cat: puma.sock: No such device or address

Comment: Before too much worry, I would try reboot. $shutdown -r now reboots the server, so only do it if you're okay with that. With the clean slate, now start your app and if you see that .sock error again, then it's time to dig into puma and nginx config files and examine the socket setups. I don't see how this would have been caused by changing the root user password, though. Hopefully a Puma person will come and answer the question 100%. Good luck!